# unauthenticated issues on Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Goal:
Basically, I want to retrieve the user attributes/identity ID using the users' STS credentials (access, secret, session keys). I'm writing a java servlet (server side), and my client is passing the STS credentials over HTTP.

Problem:
I am getting unauthenticated issues on the servlet. Below is my Java Code.

```
BasicSessionCredentials bsccreds = new BasicSessionCredentials(access, secret, session);
        AmazonCognitoSyncClient cogni = new AmazonCognitoSyncClient(bsccreds);

        AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(bsccreds);
        GetIdRequest idRequest = new GetIdRequest();
        idRequest.setRequestCredentials(bsccreds);
        idRequest.setAccountId("51xxxxxxxx");
        idRequest.setIdentityPoolId("us-east-1:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx");

        GetIdResult idResp = identityClient.getId(idRequest); // this line is giving unauthenticated issues even though i pass the STS credentials.
        String uuid = idResp.getIdentityId();
        ListRecordsRequest lrr = new ListRecordsRequest(); 
        lrr.setIdentityPoolId("us-east-1:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx");

        ListRecordsResult lrr_res = cogni.listRecords(lrr);
```

Answer (score 0):

that is inside a lambda method? does the IAM user has permissions to use cognito?